# Product of smooth maps on manifolds ($\mathbb{S}^1$)

Tags: solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Professor Lee's book on Smooth Manifolds has the following problem:

> Show that $p_n: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, given in complex notation by $p_n(z)=z^n$, is a smooth map.

I have a proof which uses angle charts. I have another idea for a proof and I'm unsure if such a solution is correct. Please check for mistakes.

**Proof:**

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f,g$ smooth maps $M\xrightarrow{f,\\ g} \mathbb{S}^1$. If we show that the standard complex multiplication $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ is smooth, then so is the product $f\cdot  g$ which factors as $$M\xrightarrow{f \times g} \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1 \xrightarrow{\cdot} \mathbb{S}^1,$$ is smooth by composition. $f\times g$ is smooth since each component function is. Hence to show that $p_n$ is smooth, it is enough to show that $p_2$ is smooth.

Comment: Your solution is correct if you can show that the multiplication is smooth. Do you already know that the restriction of a smooth map to a smooth submanifold is smooth?

Comment: Ah great! Thank you so much. That detail slipped my mind.

Comment: No you did not. But you can use this to show that the $p_2$ is smooth: it is the restriction of the multiplication $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$!

Comment: Note that you can directly use this fact to show that $z \mapsto z^n$ is smooth: it is the restriction of $z\in \Bbb C \mapsto z^n \in \Bbb C$, which is polynomial